# No Historical Data in IDO DB with Icinga2 Web2

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ansible, ido, icinga

## Context

I'm working on provisioning `Icinga2` `Web2` with `IDO PostgreSQL` and `IDO MySQL` using `Ansible` on `CentOS 7`.

I base my work on the great https://github.com/Icinga/icinga2-ansible roles. I have forked the project (mickael-ange/icinga2-ansible) to added more automation and support such as IDO PostgreSQL. I'm using PostgreSQL server 9.4.

Well, I ends up with a version of `icinga2-ansible-web2-ui` role which installs Icinga2 Web2 with IDO PostgreSQL or IDO MySQL automatically **without wizard**.

## My Problem

The server seems to work properly at the exception that I cannot figure out how to get data in Icinga2 Web2 interface such as:

- `Comments` and `Downtimes` from `Overview` menu
- `Event Grid`, `Event Overview`, `Notifications`, `Timeline` from `History` menu

I can create `Comments` and `Schedule Downtimes`, but they don't get listed in the UI. Downtimes are processed correctly.

I can send `Notifications` but they don't get listed in the UI as well. Notifications are sent out when SELinux is in permissive mode.

My questions is: **is there any IDO or Icinga2 Web2 configuration to get the database populate with Comments, Downtimes, etc..?**

My `/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-pgsql.conf`

```
library "db_ido_pgsql"

object IdoPgsqlConnection "ido-pgsql" {
  user = "icinga"
  password = "icinga"
  host = "localhost"
  database = "icinga"
  table_prefix = "icinga_"
  instance_name = "icinga2"
  instance_description = "icinga2 instance"

  cleanup = {
    downtimehistory_age = 48h
    logentries_age = 31d
  }

  categories = DbCatConfig | DbCatState
}
```

## Notes

### Note 1

I have already searched in most of the documentation of Icinga2 project and forums I could find but no cigar. I'm surprise none gets this problem before so it is probably a problem on my side.

### Note 2

After chatting on Icinga IRC channel and doing more tests I figure out that **my problem only happens with PostgreSQL backend**. It is working as expected with MySQL backend.

## Debugging Sessions

### Debugging session 1

I have gathered more info/logs about my environments.

#### PostgreSQL Permissions

I checked my PostgreSQL permissions for icinga user:

- `TABLE` permissions are set to `SELECT`,`INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE`
- `SEQUENCE` permissions are set to `USAGE`

I even tried configuring `postgres` as user to access to the backend (`icinga_ido` and `icingaweb_ido` resources) but I'm still not getting any `Comments` listed in the UI (after having created a comment).

Here are the PosgreSQL permissions listed by `\dp` command:

```
icinga=> \dp
                                                             Access privileges
 Schema |                              Name                               |   Type   |     Access privileges     | Column access privileges 
--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------------------+--------------------------
 public | icinga_acknowledgements                                         | table    | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres+| 
        |                                                                 |          | icinga=arwd/postgres      | 
 public | icinga_acknowledgements_acknowledgement_id_seq                  | sequence | postgres=rwU/postgres    +| 
        |                                                                 |          | icinga=U/postgres         | 
 public | icinga_commands                                                 | table    | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres+| 
        |                                                                 |          | icinga=arwd/postgres      | 
 public | icinga_commands_command_id_seq                                  | sequence | postgres=rwU/postgres    +| 
        |                                                                 |          | icinga=U/postgres         | 
 public | icinga_commenthistory                                           | table    | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres+| 
        |                                                                 |          | icinga=arwd/postgres      | 
 public | icinga_commenthistory_commenthistory_id_seq                     | sequence | postgres=rwU/postgres    +| 
        |                                                                 |          | icinga=U/postgres         | 
<truncated>
```

Furthermore, I have no error in PostgreSQL logs (e.g. /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_log/postgresql-Thu.log) when creatinh `Comment` from Icinga UI.

However, I figured out there are errors when trying to browse `SEQUENCE` from `pgAdmin` UI using `icinga` user (no error with `postgres` user):

```
< 2016-01-21 03:55:52.436 GMT >STATEMENT:  SELECT last_value, min_value, max_value, cache_value, is_cycled, increment_by, is_called
      FROM icinga_acknowledgements_acknowledgement_id_seq
```

But I'm not sure if it makes sense or not as `icinga` user has only `USAGE` permission on `SEQUENCE`.

#### Comparing PostgreSQL and MySQL Backends' Debug Logs

So I ends up with comparing Icinga debug logs on both sides (MySQL IDO and PostgreSQL IDO) when I creates a comment. I can see that only with MySQL backend there are the SQL statements I was looking for, whom insert data in `icinga_externalcommands`, `icinga_comments`,  and `icinga_commenthistory` tables.

I don't have enough reputation to provide more than 2 links (e.g. pastebin). So here are the logs.

**Adding a `Comment` with PostgreSQL backend:**

```
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] information/ExternalCommandListener: Executing external command: [1453349640] ADD_HOST_COMMENT;icinga2-web2-postgres;1;icingaadmin;dededewdwwewdew
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] debug/DbEvents: add external command history
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] notice/ExternalCommandProcessor: Creating comment for host icinga2-web2-postgres
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] information/ConfigCompiler: Compiling config file: /var/lib/icinga2/api/packages/_api/icinga2-web2-postgres-1453347670-1/conf.d/comments/icinga2-web2-postgres!icinga2-web2-postgres-1453349640-1.conf
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Committing config items
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] warning/ApplyRule: Apply rule 'satellite-host' (in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/satellite.conf: 29:1-29:41) for type 'Dependency' does not match anywhere!
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] warning/ApplyRule: Apply rule '' (in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf: 57:1-57:65) for type 'Service' does not match anywhere!
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] warning/ApplyRule: Apply rule '' (in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf: 65:1-65:53) for type 'Service' does not match anywhere!
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Instantiated 1 Comment.
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Triggering Start signal for config items
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Activated all objects.
[2016-01-21 04:14:00 +0000] notice/Comment: Added comment 'icinga2-web2-postgres!icinga2-web2-postgres-1453349640-1'.
[2016-01-21 04:14:01 +0000] debug/IdoPgsqlConnection: Query: COMMIT
[2016-01-21 04:14:01 +0000] debug/IdoPgsqlConnection: Query: BEGIN
```

**Adding a `Comment` with MySQL backend:**

```
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] information/ExternalCommandListener: Executing external command: [1453349569] ADD_HOST_COMMENT;icinga2-web2-mysql;1;icingaadmin;yggygyyj
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] debug/DbEvents: add external command history
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] notice/ExternalCommandProcessor: Creating comment for host icinga2-web2-mysql
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] information/ConfigCompiler: Compiling config file: /var/lib/icinga2/api/packages/_api/icinga2-web2-mysql-1453347256-1/conf.d/comments/icinga2-web2-mysql!icinga2-web2-mysql-1453349569-0.conf
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Committing config items
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] warning/ApplyRule: Apply rule 'satellite-host' (in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/satellite.conf: 29:1-29:41) for type 'Dependency' does not match anywhere!
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] warning/ApplyRule: Apply rule '' (in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf: 57:1-57:65) for type 'Service' does not match anywhere!
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] warning/ApplyRule: Apply rule '' (in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf: 65:1-65:53) for type 'Service' does not match anywhere!
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Instantiated 1 Comment.
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Triggering Start signal for config items
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Activated all objects.
[2016-01-21 04:12:49 +0000] notice/Comment: Added comment 'icinga2-web2-mysql!icinga2-web2-mysql-1453349569-0'.

[2016-01-21 04:12:50 +0000] debug/IdoMysqlConnection: Query: INSERT INTO icinga_externalcommands (command_args, command_name, command_type, endpoint_object_id, entry_time, instance_id) VALUES ('icinga2-web2-mysql;1;icingaadmin;yggygyyj', 'ADD_HOST_COMMENT', '1', 1, FROM_UNIXTIME(1453349569), 1)
[2016-01-21 04:12:50 +0000] debug/IdoMysqlConnection: Query: INSERT INTO icinga_comments (author_name, comment_data, comment_source, comment_time, comment_type, endpoint_object_id, entry_time, entry_time_usec, entry_type, expires, instance_id, internal_comment_id, is_persistent, name, object_id) VALUES ('icingaadmin', 'yggygyyj', '1', FROM_UNIXTIME(1453349569), '2', 1, FROM_UNIXTIME(1453349569), '947563', '1', '0', 1, '1', '1', 'icinga2-web2-mysql!icinga2-web2-mysql-1453349569-0', 68)
[2016-01-21 04:12:50 +0000] debug/IdoMysqlConnection: Query: INSERT INTO icinga_commenthistory (author_name, comment_data, comment_source, comment_time, comment_type, endpoint_object_id, entry_time, entry_time_usec, entry_type, expires, instance_id, internal_comment_id, is_persistent, name, object_id) VALUES ('icingaadmin', 'yggygyyj', '1', FROM_UNIXTIME(1453349569), '2', 1, FROM_UNIXTIME(1453349569), '947563', '1', '0', 1, '1', '1', 'icinga2-web2-mysql!icinga2-web2-mysql-1453349569-0', 68)
[2016-01-21 04:12:50 +0000] debug/IdoMysqlConnection: Query: COMMIT
[2016-01-21 04:12:50 +0000] debug/IdoMysqlConnection: Query: BEGIN
```

**Restarting Icinga2 with PostgreSQL and MySQL Backends**

When restarting Icinga2 with both PostgreSQL and MySQL Backends, I have pretty much the same logs which sounds good!

```
# Icinga2 restart with PostgreSQL

[2016-01-21 05:02:11 +0000] information/Application: Received request to shut down.
[2016-01-21 05:02:11 +0000] information/Application: Shutting down...
[2016-01-21 05:02:11 +0000] information/CheckerComponent: Checker stopped.
[2016-01-21 05:02:11 +0000] information/DbConnection: Resuming IDO connection: ido-pgsql
[2016-01-21 05:02:11 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Activated all objects.
[2016-01-21 05:02:11 +0000] information/ConfigCompiler: Compiling config file: /var/lib/icinga2/modified-attributes.conf
[2016-01-21 05:02:11 +0000] information/IdoPgsqlConnection: pgSQL IDO instance id: 1 (schema version: '1.14.0')

# Icinga2 restart with MySQL

[2016-01-21 05:03:20 +0000] information/Application: Received request to shut down.
[2016-01-21 05:03:20 +0000] information/Application: Shutting down...
[2016-01-21 05:03:20 +0000] information/CheckerComponent: Checker stopped.
[2016-01-21 05:03:20 +0000] information/DbConnection: Resuming IDO connection: ido-mysql
[2016-01-21 05:03:20 +0000] information/ConfigItem: Activated all objects.
[2016-01-21 05:03:20 +0000] information/ConfigCompiler: Compiling config file: /var/lib/icinga2/modified-attributes.conf
[2016-01-21 05:03:20 +0000] information/IdoMysqlConnection: MySQL IDO instance id: 1 (schema version: '1.14.0')
```

**Packages Version**

- icinga2-2.4.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
- icinga2-ido-pgsql-2.4.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
- postgresql94-9.4.5-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
- postgresql94-server-9.4.5-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64

## How to Reproduce this Issue

For those who has the energy to reproduce the problem you can clone `mickael-ange/icinga2-ansible` Github repo (branch: Issue-No-Historical-Data-in-Icinga2-Web2-and-DB) and follow instructions at [icinga2-we2-vagrant.md](https://github.com/mickael-ange/icinga2-ansible/blob/Issue-No-Historical-Data-in-Icinga2-Web2-and-DB/doc/icinga2-web2-vagrant.md). You need to install the required tools if it is not already the case. Then install role dependencies with librarian-ansible. Finally, I wrote a section (#ido-no-historical-data-in-icinga2-web2-and-db) to reproduce the problem.

Thank you in advance to take the time read until here!
Mickael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out why historical data were not inserted into the DB, so I'm here responding to myself.

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/object-types#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/object-types#objecttype-idomysqlconnection):

> categories    **Optional**.  The types of information that should be written to the database.

So when I removed categories from my `ido-pgsql.conf` configuration. I restart Icinga2 then the data are written in the DB as expected. `Comments`, `Downtimes`, well everything I wanted is listed the UI now.

I also removed the `cleanup` section as it is probably not what I want too.

The final `ido-pgsql.conf` configuration:

```
library "db_ido_pgsql"

object IdoPgsqlConnection "ido-pgsql" {
  user = "icinga"
  password = "icinga"
  host = "localhost"
  database = "icinga"
  table_prefix = "icinga_"
  instance_name = "icinga2"
  instance_description = "icinga2 instance"
}
```